# Matlab plot: auto update corresponding y when x changed

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot with X and Y, when I update the range of X, the vector size would change, so Y need to be assigned again like this:

`>> y = sin(x)`

If I don't do that, I normally got:

```
>> plot (x,y)
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.
```

So I wonder, If there's a way of making that automatically done

Comment: from your listing it's not clear what you're trying to do, shouldn't the plot command be `plot(x, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4)`?

Comment: @mutzmatron no, they share the same range of X

Comment: So you're saying you change `x` and you want to be able to call `plot(x,y)` without setting `y=sin(x)` again? Your only option then is to use a function as I suggested in my answer. In fact you can go one step further and create `plotsin = @(x)plot(x, sin(x))`. Then all you need to call is `plotsin(x)` for any `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make `y` a function (handle),

```
y = @(x)sin(x)
plot (x,y(x),x2,y(x2),x3,y(x3),x4,y(x4))
```

Of course with such a simple function you could just stick with `sin` too, i.e.

```
plot (x,sin(x),x2,sin(x2),x3,sin(x3),x4,sin(x4))
```

You could combine the `plot` command too to simplify the call further:

```
plotsin = @(x)plot(sin(x));
```

such that you can call

```
plotsin(x);
```

for any input `x`

Comment: It worked, but what about syntax of `@`, is there a document I could read about, If it's available in matlab's help, what should I read ?

Comment: '@' is used to create a _function handle_ - see here for more details http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brfpxhw-1.html